# javascript - site content update listener

Tags: javascript

I'm new in `javascript`. I'm writing user script to have some additional functionality on public internet resource. There is a content updated dynamical by built-in scripts. Is it possible to detect changes in `body` using pure `javascript` and perform my script action?

Comment: No. Why don't you just run the functions at the time of the update?

Comment: You can use this plugin to detect changes on the DOM (is not only for jQuery there is also library agnostic version).

https://github.com/darcyclarke/jQuery-Watch-Plugin.

Otherwise as suggested why you do not simply fire your functions right after the content is retrieved from the dynamics built-in scripts?

Comment: @pm.calabrese Don't want use any additional plugins. Second advice is good for me. Can you give me actual advice how i should do this, or else information which can help me?

Comment: I dont know your code... so i cant really help. But ideally if you have a function for update your data in that callback you can fire your function. If you post some code might be easier help you

Comment: My script contains only basic functionality - adding new `div` with data. But when built-in script is firing my `div` is missing. I think i can make it by other way - loop which checking difference between old data and new data and fire my script. It's a not good way, i think, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think [mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events) is as close as you get. Note that this is not supported in IE:

```
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
    var element = e.target;

    console.log(element, 'inserted in to document');
});

$('#insert').click(function() {
    $('body').append($('<div/>'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/da6vR/